# Translation of John Nash's 1962 Navier-Stokes paper

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, translation-request, mathematical-french

Is anyone aware of an English translation of the following paper of John Nash?

- John Nash, [Le Probleme de Cauchy pour les equations differentielles d'un fluide general](https://doi.org/10.24033/bsmf.1586), Bulletin de la Société Mathématique de France, tome 90 (1962), p. 487-497.

Comment: If you scroll down on [this page](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207477/john-nashs-mathematical-legacy/207510), the user @bob-terrell has a translation of it (hopefully this ping works).

Comment: The link you mention (www.math.cornell.edu/~bterrell/nash.ps) is unfortunately broken. Thanks for the find though. I'll dig deeper.

Comment: According to his page at Cornell (link: https://math.cornell.edu/robert-terrell) Bob Terrell has retired.  The page contains an email address through which you could try contacting him.

Answer (score 4):

The broken link `www.math.cornell.edu/~bterrell/nash.ps` was archived by the Wayback Machine. Here's the [latest snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20130609082225/http://www.math.cornell.edu/%7Ebterrell/nash.ps). Unfortunately it was a while before the comment of Terrell, so perhaps it is not complete. I've converted the `.ps` file to thirteen `.png`s, one for each page, and uploaded them to [this imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vNRb.jpg). I don't suppose many people will be using the bottom of this page, so I have included the pictures directly in this Answer.

PS: I was a little too enthusiastic about posting this answer, but I have now asked Bob Terrell for permission on the [linked](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207477/john-nashs-mathematical-legacy/207510) MO post, and he had [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207477/john-nashs-mathematical-legacy/207510#comment1060990_207486) to say: [(screenshot of comment)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoFkU.png)

> @CalvinKhor, that's alright with me, and I'm happy if anyone can learn from it. It should be clear that it was my attempt to begin understanding the paper. I didn't get too far, but after all to study 3D compressible viscous flow in the Lagrange description is a big thing.

[image: page 487]
[image: page 488]

[image: page 489]
[image: page 490]
[image: page 491]
[image: page 492]
[image: page 493]
[image: page 494]
[image: page 495]
[image: page 496]
[image: page 497]
[image: footnotes1]
[image: footnotes2]